# How code generate from protege data property with getter single value instead collection?

Tags: code-generation, owl, protege

I have a simple model in protege of class and data property.
But when I use code generator - in generated class - property getter have type - Collection< String > instead simple String.

I try to add something like with different types predicate in class:
"title some xsd:string"
But it is Collection yet.

Is it can be done in protege and how? May be example ontology?

Comment: By default, an individual in OWL can have multiple values for the same property. You should try making the property **functional**, that might influence the code generator.

Comment: I tried the plugin, looks like functional property characteristic doesn't change the output. You could open a [feature request](https://github.com/protegeproject/code-generation/issues) or just implement it by yourself, the code is open source: https://github.com/protegeproject/code-generation